# Why are there no options for this configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, simple-product, associate-products

Im having some trouble with some configurable products, for some reason on the backend this configurable product has 56 associated products attached too it, but when you view it on the front it doesn't show any options at all.

Front End:

[image]

Back End:

[image]

and before you ask the quantities is set at 0, it is enabled, its in the correct store, and the visibility is set to catalog, search.

Its annoying because its not viewable on the front end when looking through the catalog but its viewable when you put in the url.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Did you rebuild the indexes?

Comment: Rebuilt the indexes several times, cleared the cache on the website and my browser, even tried different browsers, still nothing.

Comment: Make sure you have a category ticked off for the configurable product itself.  Only thing I can think if the direct url works.

Comment: All the configurable products are in a category, but the simple products are not.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you have to go into the configurable product and then select a simple product from the list of associated products and set the status to enabled and the tax class to shipping to get it to show up on the front,

But because I have over 23000 simple products I tried to do this in mass by selecting all the simple products and updating the attributes to have the correct status and shipping class, but that didn't work.

I'm gonna have to go into each individual product and change the status to enabled and tax class to shipping to get it to show up.

Comment: Set your grid to display simple products only. Then select all and mass update those 2 attributes. Reindex and done.  Reindex is key when mass update.  Product save at product level forces reindex is the difference.

Comment: I did but for some reason you have to go through the configurable product to view the simple product as you can't the simple product through manage products as it doesn't show when you search for it, I have over 23000 simple products but it only shows 4000 on the manage products page, can magento even handle this many products ?

Comment: If that's the case, you have a bigger problem you need to deal with first there.  You should definitely be able to access the simples through the grid.  Perhaps some info missing from your import, like store or website association.

Comment: all the simple products have the exact sample attributes, only thing thats different is title, price,sku etc nothing major.

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with your products.  But it sounds like you were missing something on the import which is why they aren't visible in the grid.  Of course, this is just a correlation drawn from my years of experience and shooting in the dark with the given information.  If I were in your shoes, I would not just live with that scenario...

Comment: Cheers, but whats weird is that they do exsist, because when I view all my products in the manage categories section I have over 26000 products but when I goto manage products I only have 4000, I don't understand why its doing this, isn't there an extension which would reindex everything, because the built in magento one doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Check you have all these columns http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e94eay5aa

Comment: I would but I cant export the simple products because I get a 500 internal sever error when trying to export them using export and data profiles export.

Comment: Stack Exchange is wanting us to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21069/discussion-between-ladle3000-and-mrjoshfisher).

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points. It could be one of them:

1. Check you have at least one associated product with the respective configurable product.
2. Check the associated product has more than one quantity and it is "in stock"
3. Check whether the configurable options(e.g. size, color etc) are selected for the associated simple products.
4. Check you have included the configurable product and its associated products in same category you are currently viewing.

Rebuild all the indexes, clear cache and then check.

Hope this helps.